# c# chart control remove spaces between bars in bar chart

Tags: c#, winforms, mschart

I have a bar chart made with the c# .net chart control that looks like the following:
[image]

As you can see there is a space between each pair of red and blue bars on the chart. Is there a way to remove those spaces?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Here are the lines from the designer

```
 chartArea1.Name = "ChartArea1";
            this.CHRT_DPS_HPS.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea1);
            legend1.Name = "Legend1";
            this.CHRT_DPS_HPS.Legends.Add(legend1);
            this.CHRT_DPS_HPS.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 271);
            this.CHRT_DPS_HPS.Name = "CHRT_DPS_HPS";
            series1.ChartArea = "ChartArea1";
            series1.ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Bar;
            series1.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            series1.Legend = "Legend1";
            series1.MarkerBorderWidth = 0;
            series1.Name = "DPS";
            series1.XValueType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartValueType.String;
            series1.YValueType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartValueType.Double;
            series2.ChartArea = "ChartArea1";
            series2.ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Bar;
            series2.Legend = "Legend1";
            series2.MarkerBorderWidth = 0;
            series2.Name = "HPS";
            series2.XValueType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartValueType.String;
            series2.YValueType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartValueType.Double;
            this.CHRT_DPS_HPS.Series.Add(series1);
            this.CHRT_DPS_HPS.Series.Add(series2);
            this.CHRT_DPS_HPS.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1199, 300);
            this.CHRT_DPS_HPS.TabIndex = 1;
            this.CHRT_DPS_HPS.Text = "CHRT_DPS_HPS";
            title1.Name = "Title1";
            title1.Text = "DPS Chart";
            this.CHRT_DPS_HPS.Titles.Add(title1);
```

Comment: Can you post the code that you used to generate this graph?

Comment: It was all done with drag and drop in design view.

Comment: If you open the Form.Designer.cs file, you will see the code that is generated by the designer.  Can you paste the lines that pertain to the chart control?

Comment: I added the lines of code in an edit. Thanks for all the quick responses Kyle!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to set a custom property for that chart type.

Use this for each series (my code specifies series zero):

```
chart1.Series[0]["PointWidth"] = "1";
```

Replace the zero with the name and or indices of your series.

By the way - as much as it does have its limitations here and there - Microsoft Charting is quite a capable charting library!  You just have to read the documentation.  In this case, this chart type has special custom properties you can utilize.

This worked in my test application.  Let me know if it does not work with yours and I will perform further troubleshooting.

As I am new and trying to gain rep, please mark my response as the answer if it is correct. Thank you.

Comment: This works on System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting too. although it is just increasing size of border lines for each bar, but it works and I am happy enough.