# How I can get space between the bars of my chart?

Tags: c#, charts

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzY6q.png

I'm building this chart in a windows forms application using c# and I didn't find a way to separate the bars of the chart. As you can see in the images they are "glued".
Anyone can help me with that? What I'm doing wrong? Please see the link to check my actual chart.

Thank you

my code:

```
    private void InitChart()
    {
        if (AvaliacaoFisica != null)
        {
            // Data arrays.
            string[] seriesArray = { "Ombros", "Peito", "Brç Dir", "Brç Esq", "Cintura", "Abs", "Anca", "Coxa Drt", "Coxa Esq" };//"Altura", "Peso", "Idade",
            double[] pointsArray = { 
                                     double.Parse(AvaliacaoFisica.PerOmbros.ToString(), System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), double.Parse(AvaliacaoFisica.PerPeito.ToString(), System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),  double.Parse(AvaliacaoFisica.PerBracoDir.ToString(), System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                                     double.Parse(AvaliacaoFisica.PerBracoEsq.ToString(), System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), double.Parse(AvaliacaoFisica.PerCintura.ToString(), System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), double.Parse(AvaliacaoFisica.PerAbs.ToString(), System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                                     double.Parse(AvaliacaoFisica.PerAnca.ToString(), System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), double.Parse(AvaliacaoFisica.PerCoxaEsq.ToString(), System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), double.Parse(AvaliacaoFisica.PerCoxaDrt.ToString(), System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                                   };//double.Parse(AvaliacaoFisica.Altura.ToString(), System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) * 100, double.Parse(AvaliacaoFisica.Peso.ToString(), System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), dcsDB.GetInt(AvaliacaoFisica.Idade),

            // Set palette.
            this.chart1.Palette = ChartColorPalette.Fire;   //Colors group for chart
            this.chart1.BackColor = Color.Transparent;      //Background Color
            this.chart1.ForeColor = Color.White;

            // Set title.
            this.chart1.Titles.Add(
                new Title(
                    "Estatísticas - " + AvaliacaoFisica.DtAvaliacao.ToShortDateString(), //Title String
                    Docking.Top,                                                        //Location
                    new Font("Verdana", 13f, FontStyle.Bold),                           //Font Type
                    Color.White                                                         //Font Color
                )
            );

            chart1.Legends.Add("Legenda");

            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.TitleForeColor = Color.White;    //Cor da legenda do eixo x
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Title = "TESTE X";               //título da legenda do eixo do x
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.TitleForeColor = Color.White;    //Cor da legenda do eixo y
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Title = "TESTE Y";               //título da legenda do eixo y

            //chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 5;                    //Definir intervalo de numeração no eixo do x


            // Add series.
            for (int i = 0; i < seriesArray.Length; i++)
            {
                // Add series.
                Series series = this.chart1.Series.Add(seriesArray[i]);

                //Legenda das barras do gráfico com nome e valor
                series.Label = seriesArray[i].ToString() + " " + pointsArray[i].ToString();        //Texto
                series.LabelToolTip = seriesArray[i].ToString() + " " + pointsArray[i].ToString(); //ToolTip
                series.LegendToolTip = pointsArray[i].ToString();                                   //ToolTip Legenda
                series.LabelBackColor = Color.YellowGreen;                                          //Cor de fundo do texto

                // Add point.
                series.Points.Add(pointsArray[i]);
                series.AxisLabel = " OI ";
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: [PointWidth (Chart Controls)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd456723%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Reference [c# chart control remove spaces between bars in bar chart](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6837401/2596334)